how to remove a left margin in an itemize for a tcolorbox?
I would like to remove the left white margin of a tcolorbox when it is under an itemized list.
It is fine to have the margin for the itemized text, but just not for the tcolorbox (which is included as part of the item).
Here is a MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item left margin fine for a long item here

\begin{tcolorbox}
I don't want itemize to give left margin here to the box, the box should be more to the left
\end{tcolorbox}

\item Item B

\end{itemize}

\end{document}


Use grow to left by.
Example, with grow to left by=\leftmargin to remove totally the margin added by itemize
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}

\item left margin fine for a long item here

  \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=\leftmargin]
    I don't want itemize to give left margin here to the box, the box should be more to the left
  \end{tcolorbox}

\item Item B

\end{itemize}

\end{document}


